# nhibernate querying a collection

Tags: nhibernate, collections

Imagine a database structure where you have a `Class` and `Student`, and Student has one class, and vice-versa, a class has many students.

How would one go in Nhibernate to create a query, (Preferably QueryOver or Criteria API), for the following.

```
Select ANY class which contains BOTH StudentA and StudentB.
```

If it was a disjunction (OR), I could do it by specifying

```
List<Student> studentRestrictionList = new List<Student>();
studentRestrictionList.Add(studentA);
studentRestrictionList.Add(studentB);
Student studentAlias = null;
var q = session.QueryOver<Class>();
q.Left.JoinAlias(item => item.Students, () => studentsAlias);
q.WhereRestrictionOn(() => studentsAlias.ID)IsInG(studentRestrictionList);
```

The problem starts when I need to do a conjunction (AND).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get conjunction, I would create a separate conjunction object and attach it to the criteria(again, untested but should get you on the right track):

```
var q = DetachedCriteria.For<Class>()
 .CreateCriteria("this.Students", "student");

var con = new Conjunction();
foreach(var s in studentList)
{
 con.Add(Restrictions.Eq("student.Id", s.Id));
}

q.Add(con);
```

Comment: Isn't that still disjunctive?

Comment: yes, all the problem I cannot seem to implement is when you need an AND-ed query, not an OR (disjunction).  I know how to do it in SQL-terms, but not in NH-terms.  Preferably, I would like to avoid HQL as I find it a bit of a maintenance nightmare